# Elements $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]/I$ which satisfy $f^{18}=1$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $(X^2+2)(X+1)$ and $5$. Then, how many elements  $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]/I$ satisfy $f^{18}=1$?

I know that I can write $f(X)=aX^2+bX+c$ ($a,b,c=0\sim 4$) in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/I $, but it is too hard to calculate $f^{18}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring $R=\Bbb Z[X]/I$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_5\times \Bbb F_{25}$.

In $\Bbb F_5$, $t^{18}=1$ has two solutions, as $\gcd(5-1,18)=2$.

In $\Bbb F_{25}$, $t^{18}=1$ has six solutions, as $\gcd(25-1,18)=6$.

Therefore $R$ has twelve solutions to $t^{18}=1$.

Comment: Justification for first step: $$\begin{array}{cl} & \Bbb Z[X]/(5,(X^2+2)(X+1)) \\ \cong & \Bbb F_5[X]/((X^2+2)(X+1)) \\ \cong & \Bbb F_5[X]/(X^2+2) \times \Bbb F_5[X]/(X+1) \\ \cong & \Bbb F_{25} \times \Bbb F_5 \end{array}$$ (chinese remainder theorem; $X^2+2$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_5[X]$)